# NSTableView's delegate receive awakeFromNib message when a row is created

Tags: cocoa

In my project there is a xib file whose File Owner is set to a subclass of **NSViewController**. This xib file has a NSView with a **View Based NSTableView** inside. The NSViewController subclass implements the protocol **NSTableViewDelegate** and, in IB, the NSTableView's delegate is connected to File's Owner. When a view is created by bindings, the **awakeFromNib** method of the viewController gets called with this call stack:

```
#0  0x000000010000584b in -[TheViewController awakeFromNib] 
#1  0x00007fff890f9bd8 in -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:topLevelObjects:] ()
#2  0x00007fff893101d6 in -[NSNib _instantiateNibWithExternalNameTable:] ()
#3  0x00007fff89310c7a in -[NSNib instantiateNibWithExternalNameTable:] ()
#4  0x00007fff892bcac4 in -[NSTableRowData _unarchiveViewWithIdentifier:owner:] ()
#5  0x00007fff892be57b in -[NSTableView(NSTableViewViewBased) makeViewForTableColumn:row:] ()
#6  0x00007fff892be1b2 in -[NSTableRowData _addViewToRowView:atColumn:row:] ()
#7  0x00007fff892bde7f in -[NSTableRowData _addViewsToRowView:atRow:] ()
#8  0x00007fff892bc415 in -[NSTableRowData _addRowViewForVisibleRow:withPriorView:] ()
#9  0x00007fff892bc19a in -[NSTableRowData _addRowViewForVisibleRow:withPriorRowIndex:inDictionary:withRowAnimation:] ()
#10 0x00007fff892bb469 in -[NSTableRowData _unsafeUpdateVisibleRowEntries] ()
#11 0x00007fff892bb001 in -[NSTableRowData updateVisibleRowViews] ()
#12 0x00007fff892930fb in -[NSTableView viewWillDraw] ()
#13 0x00007fff89170bed in __22-[NSView viewWillDraw]_block_invoke_0 ()
#14 0x00007fff884d50b6 in __NSArrayEnumerate ()
#15 0x00007fff8917092d in -[NSView viewWillDraw] ()
#16 0x00007fff89170bed in __22-[NSView viewWillDraw]_block_invoke_0 ()
#17 0x00007fff884d50b6 in __NSArrayEnumerate ()
#18 0x00007fff8917092d in -[NSView viewWillDraw] ()
#19 0x00007fff891fb455 in -[NSScrollView viewWillDraw] ()
#20 0x00007fff89170bed in __22-[NSView viewWillDraw]_block_invoke_0 ()
#21 0x00007fff884d50b6 in __NSArrayEnumerate ()
#22 0x00007fff8917092d in -[NSView viewWillDraw] ()
#23 0x00007fff89170bed in __22-[NSView viewWillDraw]_block_invoke_0 ()
#24 0x00007fff884d50b6 in __NSArrayEnumerate ()
#25 0x00007fff8917092d in -[NSView viewWillDraw] ()
#26 0x00007fff89247e0d in -[NSBox viewWillDraw] ()
#27 0x00007fff89170bed in __22-[NSView viewWillDraw]_block_invoke_0 ()
#28 0x00007fff884d50b6 in __NSArrayEnumerate ()
#29 0x00007fff8917092d in -[NSView viewWillDraw] ()
#30 0x00007fff89170bed in __22-[NSView viewWillDraw]_block_invoke_0 ()
#31 0x00007fff884d50b6 in __NSArrayEnumerate ()
#32 0x00007fff8917092d in -[NSView viewWillDraw] ()
#33 0x00007fff89170bed in __22-[NSView viewWillDraw]_block_invoke_0 ()
#34 0x00007fff884d50b6 in __NSArrayEnumerate ()
#35 0x00007fff8917092d in -[NSView viewWillDraw] ()
#36 0x00007fff89170bed in __22-[NSView viewWillDraw]_block_invoke_0 ()
#37 0x00007fff884d50b6 in __NSArrayEnumerate ()
#38 0x00007fff8917092d in -[NSView viewWillDraw] ()
#39 0x00007fff8916ff84 in -[NSView _sendViewWillDrawInRect:clipRootView:] ()
#40 0x00007fff8913c3f1 in -[NSView displayIfNeeded] ()
#41 0x00007fff891f93f8 in -[NSWindow _reallyDoOrderWindow:relativeTo:findKey:forCounter:force:isModal:] ()
#42 0x00007fff891f8a18 in -[NSWindow _doOrderWindow:relativeTo:findKey:forCounter:force:isModal:] ()
#43 0x00007fff891f85ff in -[NSWindow orderWindow:relativeTo:] ()
#44 0x00007fff890f9c96 in -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:topLevelObjects:] ()
#45 0x00007fff890d8b7d in loadNib ()
#46 0x00007fff890d80a9 in +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:withZone:ownerBundle:] ()
#47 0x00007fff890d7ede in -[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:topLevelObjects:] ()
#48 0x00007fff890d7cbe in +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:] ()
#49 0x00007fff890d447f in NSApplicationMain ()
#50 0x0000000100001432 in main
```

The awakeFromNib method shouldn't be called only after the viewController is instantiated?

Comment: saw this too. Really annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like from my experience that the `File's Owner` of any **xib document** will receive an `-awakeFromNib` message **whenever a new view is loaded from that xib file**. This would, as you noticed, occur when view-based table views create new rows from the xib file.

And I know of no way to stop that from happening, except to maybe keep track of how many times you've called `awakeFromNib` and execute the initialization code only the first time.

**Or**, **better yet,** put your initialization logic in another method that has a more solid timing - e.g. in `-loadView`, after the call to `super`. I do something like:

```
- (void)loadView {
    [self vvViewWillLoad];
    [super loadView];
    [self vvViewDidLoad];
}

- (void)vvViewDidLoad {
    ... // initialization material here
}
```

Comment: This is true according to the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTableView/makeViewWithIdentifier:owner: